# Django: How to Auto-Populate field with a related-model's field

Tags: python, django

I have two basic models:

```
class ModelA(models.model):
    ... #some fields
    score = models.IntegerField()

class ModelB(models.model)
    ... #some fields
    related_model=models.OneToOneField(ModelA)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=related_model.score)
```

What I want is that upon creation of ModelB, it's score field be filled with the value of score of ModelA to which it has a OneToOne relation.

I have tried setting the `score = models.IntegerField(default=related_model.score)` but upon migration I get the error:`AttributeError: 'OneToOneField' object has no attribute 'score'`

I also tried defining a method under ModelB as follows and passing it to the default:

```
def get_score(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.threat.score
```

This doesn't work either. 
when I set `default=get_score()` I get the error: `missing one required positional argument: self`

How can I automatically set a model's field to be a field of it's related model's (by OneToOne Relation) field?

Comment: You can use [Django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/) with the `pre_save` signal for this.

Comment: @Stevy I have a hunch that there must be a simple way to accomplish this? :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do this on save.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.score:
        self.score = self.threat.score
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: The `makemigration` stage passed. But, when through the admin panel, I set the related model and leave score empty and push the save button, I get the error `This field is required.`

Comment: You will need to set it as `blank=True, null=True`.